# Joomla - how to push user profiles in articles

Tags: joomla

I am trying to get user profiles displayed as articles in a category blog. Is there a way to push some fields of the profiles as articles (and get these articles updated when the user updates the profile)?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be looking to display extended user profiles, not articles. I've used "Community Builder" extension for this. It might be an overkill for what you are trying to do, so look for extensions that extend user profiles, you won't be able to do it with Joomla "out of the box".

Answer (score 0):

Do they need to be articles (com_contact instances)? If not, you could try an alternative with the additional benefit of using core extensions, the "Contact Creator Plugin" and ["User profile"](http://docs.joomla.org/What_is_the_profile_plugin?) as It will do the work you are looking for:

1. Activate "User - Contact Creator" plugin - Every new user will have a contact profile created.
2. Configure its parameters - You can select which fields will appear in the user profile page.
3. Then you can add Add a menu item to display all your contacts (users) - Select the menu type: "Contact / List Contacts in a Category"

You can add custom fields to users following this tutorial: [Creating a profile plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin)